# Cant recognise long long , long double in MinGW on Code::Blocks

Tags: gcc, types, codeblocks, long-double, unsigned-long-long-int

I am rather new to programming in C. I am suing Code::Blocks 20.03 with MinGW (GCC) which comes as a default part of CB installation. I tried several times to declare and use long long int with %Ld or double float with %Lf. But the compiler only seems to recognise the basic old datatypes like char int and float. It gives all kinds of warning when using the 'long' variables. What could be the reason? Is there anything I can do to fix this?
Thanks in advance everyone.

I was expecting to get the codes that use long long int and long double etc. smootly on Code::Blocks with mingw.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add (copy and paste) the problematic code and the errors you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use the MinGW contained in CodeBlocks 20.03 Installer. That GCC version is 8.1.0, a bad and old one. I suggest you trying a new gcc, the best is the version higher than 10. Some websites that provide gcc-on-Windows packages can be such as [WinLibs](https://winlibs.com). After download and unpack the archive, set it up in CodeBlocks Compiler Settings.